# Laravel - Can't use a manyToMany method after join

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've a strange behavior of Laravel when I'm trying to use a belongsToMany method, only after a join.
I've these classes: Meeting, Order, Organizer, User and Product
and these pivot tables: meeting_organizer, order_product, organizer_user
And this is order class

```
class Order extends \Eloquent {
public function meeting(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Meeting');
}

public function state(){
    return $this->belongsTo('OrderState', 'order_state_id');
}

public function products(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Product')->withPivot('qty');
}

public function sellers(){
    $meeting = $this->meeting()->first();
    if($meeting) return $meeting->sellers()->get();
    else return array();
}

public function organizers(){
    $meeting = $this->meeting()->first();
    if($meeting) return $meeting->organizers()->get();
    else return array();
}
```

When I use

```
$data['records'] = Order::all();
```

and then this loop:

```
foreach( $data['records'] as $r ){
        if($r->meeting){
            $r->meeting_date = $r->meeting->date;
            $r->meeting_name = $r->meeting->name;
        }
        $r->status = $r->state->name;
        $r->delivery_date = date_format(date_create($r->delivery_date), 'm-d');

        $r->seller = '';
        foreach( $r->sellers() as $s) $r->seller .= $s->name.', ';

        $r->organizer = '';
        foreach( $r->organizers() as $o) $r->organizer .= $o->name.', ';

        $r->product = '';
        foreach( $r->products as $p) $r->product .= $p->pivot->qty ." x ". $p->name.'<br />';
    }
```

works well.

But if I use this join

```
$data['records'] = Order
    ::join('meeting_organizer', 'orders.meeting_id', '=', 'meeting_organizer.id')
    ->join('organizer_user', 'meeting_organizer.organizer_id', '=', 'organizer_user.organizer_id')
    ->where('organizer_user.user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

the loop doesn't return any products.
So, I don't get any error, only an empty result.

If I try to print on screen inside my loop `$r->id` the result is wrong and the same number for all records, but all of other properties are correct.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but you're using that join situation as a way of only getting Order where the organizer of its meeting is a given user (logged in user (btw you can use `Auth::id()`)), right? If so, maybe try using [whereHas](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations) and see if that works better. Or, if the issue is not the fact that you join but that the joining code returns nothing when it should, try `->toSql()` on that join code to make sure it's generating the SQL you expect and try running that SQL against your database manually.

Comment: You're right, I've already try to use whereHas, but in this way i've get some errors, maybe for the organizers method, instead with my joins statement i can get the rights orders, only the products result is empty

Comment: Hmm that's very odd - if you get real `Order` models, then the call to `->products` should be completely unaffected by how you actually got the `Order`s in the first place.

Comment: Ahh I've just seen the last part of your question about `$r->id` being the same for all, that's obviously what's doing it. So yeah the join is affecting the results in a weird way. Try, just before the `->get()` `->select('orders.*')` and see if that's any better. (You may also be able to put that `'orders.*'` in the call to `->get()`, saving the need for `->select()`, I can't remember right now.)

Comment: But my original point stands (in fact this shows that using joins leads to data oddities). Using `whereHas` will keep the joins and whatnot separate (though it doesn't use joins but subqueries, so you may find it not as performant). You just need to get the `whereHas` syntax right from the sounds of it.